# Stop a chronometer if a method returns true

Tags: java, android, chronometer, android-studio-3.1.3

Is there any way that the chronometer can be paused if a method is true. I have created a simple jigsaw puzzle and added a chronometer to show the time elapse and I'm trying to stop the timer when the puzzle is Solved.On running, the application runs smoothly, with the chronometer ticking but not stopping when the game is solved. Any sort of help will be appreciated.
Here is the code;

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);
    chronometer  = findViewById(R.id.chronometer);

    stopChronometer();
    startChronometer();
    isSolved();
}

public static boolean isSolved() {
    boolean solved = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < tileList.length; i++) {
        if (tileList[i].equals(String.valueOf(i))) {
            solved = true;
        } else {
            solved = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return solved;
}
//to start the chronometer
public void startChronometer(){
    if(!running){
        chronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
        chronometer.start();
        running = true;
    }
}
//to stop the chronometer
public void stopChronometer(){
    if(running && isSolved()){
        chronometer.stop();
        running =false;
    }
}
```

If interested in the whole code;

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewTreeObserver;
import android.widget.Button;
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;
import android.widget.Chronometer;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //GestureDetectView* is the class where the puzzle grid is setup
    private static GestureDetectGridView mGridView;
    private static final int COLUMNS =3;
    private static final int DIMENSIONS = COLUMNS * COLUMNS;
    private static int mColumnWidth, mColumnHeight;
    //up, down, left, right are tile movements
    public static final String up = "up";
    public static final String down = "down";
    public static final String left = "left";
    public static final String right = "right";
    private static String[] tileList;

    private Chronometer chronometer;
    private boolean running;

    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        chronometer  = findViewById(R.id.chronometer);
        init();
        scramble();
        setDimensions();
        stopChronometer();
        startChronometer();
    }

    //to start the chronometer
    public void startChronometer(){
        if(!running){
            chronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
            chronometer.start();
            running = true;
        }
    }
    //to stop the chronometer * PROBLEM AREA
    public void stopChronometer(){

    if(running && isSolved()){
        chronometer.stop();
        running =false;
        }
    }
    //Grid view from GestureDetectView class
    private void init() {
        mGridView = (GestureDetectGridView) findViewById(R.id.grid);
            mGridView.setNumColumns(COLUMNS);
        tileList = new String[DIMENSIONS];
        for (int i = 0; i < DIMENSIONS; i++) {
            tileList[i] = String.valueOf(i);
        }
    }
    //To shuffle the grid pieces
    private void scramble() {
        int index;
        String temp;
        Random random = new Random();

        for (int i = tileList.length -1; i > 0; i--) {
                index = random.nextInt(i + 1);
                temp = tileList[index];
                tileList[index] = tileList[i];
                tileList[i] = temp;
            }

        }
private void setDimensions() {
    ViewTreeObserver vto = mGridView.getViewTreeObserver();
    vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            mGridView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
            int displayWidth = mGridView.getMeasuredWidth();
            int displayHeight = mGridView.getMeasuredHeight();

            int statusbarHeight = getStatusBarHeight(getApplicationContext());
            int requiredHeight = displayHeight - statusbarHeight;

            mColumnWidth = displayWidth / COLUMNS;
            mColumnHeight = requiredHeight / COLUMNS;

            display(getApplicationContext());
                }
        });
    }

    private int getStatusBarHeight(Context context) {
        int result = 0;
        int resourceId = context.getResources().getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen",
            "android");

        if (resourceId > 0) {
         result = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
        }

        return result;
 }
    //To determine if puzzle is solved
    public static boolean isSolved() {
        boolean solved = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < tileList.length; i++)
        {
                if (tileList[i].equals(String.valueOf(i))) {
                solved = true;
            }   else {
                solved = false;
                break;
                }
        }
        return solved;
    }
    private static void swap(Context context, int Position, int swap) {
        String newPosition = tileList[Position + swap];
        tileList[Position + swap] = tileList[Position];
        tileList[Position] = newPosition;
        display(context);
        if (isSolved()) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "CONGRATULATIONS, YOU WIN!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
//To source the image pieces and add them to the puzzle grid
    private static void display(Context context) {
        ArrayList<Button> buttons = new ArrayList<>();
        Button button;

        for (int i = 0; i < tileList.length; i++) {
            button = new Button(context);

            if (tileList[i].equals("0"))
                button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.piece1);
            else if (tileList[i].equals("1"))
                button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.piece2);
            else if (tileList[i].equals("2"))
                button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.piece3);
            else if (tileList[i].equals("3"))
                button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.piece4);
            else if (tileList[i].equals("4"))
                button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.piece5);
            else if (tileList[i].equals("5"))
                button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.piece6);
            else if (tileList[i].equals("6"))
                button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.piece7);
            else if (tileList[i].equals("7"))
                button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.piece8);
            else if (tileList[i].equals("8"))
                button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.piece9);

            buttons.add(button);

        }

        mGridView.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(buttons, mColumnWidth, mColumnHeight));
    }

    public static void moveTiles(Context context, String direction, int position) {

        // Upper-left-corner tile
        if (position == 0) {

            if (direction.equals(right)) swap(context, position, 1);
            else if (direction.equals(down)) swap(context, position, COLUMNS);
            else Toast.makeText(context, "Invalid move", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            // Upper-center tiles
        }   else if (position > 0 && position < COLUMNS - 1) {
            if (direction.equals(left)) swap(context, position, -1);
            else if (direction.equals(down)) swap(context, position, COLUMNS);
            else if (direction.equals(right)) swap(context, position, 1);
            else Toast.makeText(context, "Invalid move", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            // Upper-right-corner tile
        }   else if (position == COLUMNS - 1) {
            if (direction.equals(left)) swap(context, position, -1);
            else if (direction.equals(down)) swap(context, position, COLUMNS);
            else Toast.makeText(context, "Invalid move", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            // Left-side tiles
        } else if (position > COLUMNS - 1 && position < DIMENSIONS - COLUMNS &&
            position % COLUMNS == 0) {
            if (direction.equals(up)) swap(context, position, -COLUMNS);
            else if (direction.equals(right)) swap(context, position, 1);
            else if (direction.equals(down)) swap(context, position, COLUMNS);
            else Toast.makeText(context, "Invalid move", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            // Right-side AND bottom-right-corner tiles
        } else if (position == COLUMNS * 2 - 1 || position == COLUMNS * 3 -1) 
          {
            if (direction.equals(up)) swap(context, position, -COLUMNS);
            else if (direction.equals(left)) swap(context, position, -1);
            else if (direction.equals(down)) {

            // Tolerates only the right-side tiles to swap downwards as opposed to the bottom-
            // right-corner tile.
            if (position <= DIMENSIONS - COLUMNS - 1) swap(context, position,
                    COLUMNS);
            else Toast.makeText(context, "Invalid move", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else Toast.makeText(context, "Invalid move", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            // Bottom-left corner tile
        } else if (position == DIMENSIONS - COLUMNS) {
            if (direction.equals(up)) swap(context, position, -COLUMNS);
            else if (direction.equals(right)) swap(context, position, 1);
            else Toast.makeText(context, "Invalid move", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            // Bottom-center tiles
        } else if (position < DIMENSIONS - 1 && position > DIMENSIONS - COLUMNS) {
            if (direction.equals(up)) swap(context, position, -COLUMNS);
            else if (direction.equals(left)) swap(context, position, -1);
            else if (direction.equals(right)) swap(context, position, 1);
            else Toast.makeText(context, "Invalid move", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            // Center tiles
        } else {
            if (direction.equals(up)) swap(context, position, -COLUMNS);
            else if (direction.equals(left)) swap(context, position, -1);
            else if (direction.equals(right)) swap(context, position, 1);
            else swap(context, position, COLUMNS);
        }
    }


    @Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState){
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);


    }

}
```

Comment: Are you calling `stopChronometer()` anywhere?  For example, when the player places a piece in the puzzle?

Comment: I have only called the method under  "onCreate"

Comment: Stop reposting this question.

Comment: Well, you need to call it whenever you want to check whether the chronometer should stop.  A good time would be when the player places a piece in the puzzle.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void stopChronometer() {
    if(running && isSolved()){
        chronometer.stop();
        running =false;
    }
}
```

change to

```
public void stopChronometer(){
    if(running || isSolved()){
        chronometer.stop();
        running =false;
    }
}
```

or you can call stopChronometer() from isSolved() method (you have to remove isSolved() from stopChronometer though). Without seeing the complete code, it's hard to answer.

Comment: I have done that but the timer keeps on going, just as the previous state even after "Solved" toast appearing on the screen

Comment: I seriously doubt whether this will help.  What do you expect stopping a chronometer that's not running to do?

Comment: The chronometer is running. The issue is stopping it 

Comment: can you publish the correct code for completeness?? @ErickIvuto Btw, if it worked can you accept my answer???

Comment: @SohamGoswami Let me edit to show the full code. It worked just as before as if isSolved() didnt matter in the code.

Answer (score -1):

I have found the solution
The issue whas that I hadn't declared the method start Chronometer(), chronomer and running as static. Thanks for the help though